# Second order homogeneous variable coefficient ODE (periodic perturbation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, perturbation-theory

I have trouble solving the following ODE: $$y''(t)+[\alpha -i\beta \cos(\omega t)]y'(t)-\alpha^2 y(t)=0.$$ 
where $$\alpha\gg\beta, \alpha\gg\omega$$
I was wondering is there any approach to get an approximate solution to this ODE. 
I have tried the exploratory solution like this：$$y(x)=Y(x)*e^{-i\frac{\beta}{\omega}\sin\omega t}$$, but it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply techniques of perturbation theory as follows:

Let $y$ be written in terms of a Taylor series of a small parameter, which in your case is appropriately $\beta$. So, $y  = Y_0 + \beta Y_1 + \beta^2Y_2 + O(\beta^3)$, where $Y_i$ are functions of $t$ yet to be determined.

Then this substituting this into the original equation, $y'' + (\alpha - i\beta cos(\omega t))y' - \alpha^2y = 0$, we get the following

$$(Y_0’’+\alpha Y_0’- \alpha^2 Y_0) + \beta(Y_1’’+\alpha Y_1’-\alpha^2Y_1 - icos(\omega t)Y_0)+\beta^2(Y_2’’+\alpha Y_2’- \alpha^2 Y_2 - icos(\omega t)Y_1) + O(\beta^3) = 0$$

Equating each coefficient of the powers of $\beta$ to 0, results in a system of equations. Notably:
$$Y_0''+\alpha Y_0' - \alpha^2 Y_0=0$$
$$Y_1''+\alpha Y_1' - \alpha^2Y_1 - icos(\omega t)Y_0 =0$$
$$Y_2''+\alpha Y_2' - \alpha^2 Y_2 - icos(\omega t)Y_1 = 0$$

Now, the solution to $Y_0$ is $Y_0 = c_1e^{\gamma_1t}+c_2e^{\gamma_2t}$, where $\gamma_i$ are the roots of the equation $\gamma^2+\alpha \gamma - \alpha^2=0$.
You can then solve for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ successively. I am not going to do all of the calculation work, but suffice it to say, there is a lot of algebra. For instance, take $Y_1$:
$$Y_1''+\alpha Y_1' - \alpha^2 Y_1 = icos(\omega t) Y_0= {i\over2}(e^{-i\omega t}+e^{i \omega t})(c_1e^{\gamma_1t}+c_2e^{\gamma_2t}).$$ There are four unique exponential terms on the right hand side. Consider one of them, $c_1e^{(i\omega+\gamma_1)t}$, and let $Y_{11}=d_1e^{(i\omega+\gamma_1)t}$. Then $d_1 = {i\over2}\frac{c_1}{-\alpha^2+\alpha(i\omega+\gamma_1)+(i\omega+\gamma_1)^2}={i\over2}\frac{c_1}{-\omega^2+i(\alpha + 2\gamma_1)\omega}$.

In this fashion, you can calculate $Y_1 = \sum_{i=1}^4 Y_{1i}$.

After you have solved the $Y_i$, then $y \approx Y_0+\beta Y_1 +\beta^2 Y_2$.

Comment: As a pedantic note, in perturbation theory you seek asymptotic expansions, not Taylor expansions. Importantly, asymptotic expansions (generically) do not converge, do not require positive integer powers of the small parameter, are not unique, and do not have the same interpretation with derivatives of the original function. In simple problems you do recover the Taylor series expansion of the solution, but usually this is not the case.

Comment: @David , You are right. I have tried the Taylor expansions like @ player100 mentioned above. Although I can solve the solution (Y_i) of each expansion item, the solution is inconsistent with the numerical solution. In fact, if beta=0, the solutions  are two exponential decay functions. When adding the perturbation item \beta\cos\omega t, the decay will be more fast as the beta incrased, while this phenomenon is not observed in Taylor expansions.

Comment: Out of curiosity what values of the parameters did you use for the numerical study?

Comment: the parameters: α=10000，β=10，ω=1000.  According to the results of the numerical solution, the analytical solution hould be similar to the damped oscillations function, and the attenuation constant increases as α decreases, ω decreases, or β increases. Even if I know the characteristics of the analytical solution, I still can't get the quantitative relationship between the attenuation constant and these parameters. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is your numerical method and timestepping scheme? You have a very “stiff” system where it is very likely numerical errors can grow quickly.

Comment: The stiff ODE is solved by Matlab's ODE15s function, which is specifically used to solve stiff ODE. In fact, this ODE has a corresponding physical meaning, and the variation of the numerical solution about the parameters is in line with the physical interpretation.

Comment: I found a link that describes a similar problem to yours. Look at section 8.5 here: http://pordlabs.ucsd.edu/wryoung/SIO203C2017/PartA_PerturbationTheory.pdf